# WSO2 Admin Console HTTP Access

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have been trying to configure the WSO2 Admin console for HTTP access and not HTTPS. I have a load balancer infant of my WSO2 ESB server that will terminate the inbound HTTPS connections and forward to the WSO2 server as HTTP.

I have tried various different configurations in the catalina-server.xml file without any success. It either does not work at all or when connecting using HTTP it simply redirects to HTTPS, even after removing the 'redirect' setting from the HTTP connector configuration.

I have spent several hours 'playing' and searching for something similar on the web to no avail.

Hopefully someone here has done something similar or can help.

Regards,

Graham

Answer (score 2):

I'm using wso2 esb 4.8.1,Go to the following location in your esb carbon server ,
`CARBON_HOME\repository\conf` open carbon.xml file and uncomment the following line

`<!-- Enable accessing Admin Console via HTTP -->
  <EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>`

and you will have HTTP access to your wso2esb admin console. After enabling HTTP access, you can access the admin console via port 9763.